# Files are in listing when running laravel4 project in browser

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hello guys I am new in Laravel framework. I have successfully install Laravel4 in wamp server in windows os. After that I create a new project in Laravel trhough command prompt like that:

```
c:\wampp\www> composer create-project laravel/laravel project1
```

And it successfully installed. But when I am running this project in the browser(google chrome and mozila) like the url:

```
http://localhost/project1
```

all the files are in listing manner.
So how do I start my project in Laravel. In many site I have shown that the are only using

```
http://project1.dev/
```

but when i am using it can't find the server. Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try `http://localhost/project1/public`

To get it running from `http://project1.dev` you'll need to create a `VirtualHost` (also known as `vhost` in your webserver (wamp). Here's a tutorial: http://www.codeforest.net/multiple-virtual-hosts-in-wamp

Comment: can you please tell me why "generate" is not working for me. When I am using php artisan generate:model student Then it is not working and shows InvalidArgumentException There are no commands defined in the generate namespace.

Comment: Can you run `php artisan list` to get a full ist of available command ?